# How to return optional parameters in function

Tags: python, function, return

I'd love to have a function return a number of results function of the parameters I give it.

I've already tried googling etc but didn't have any luck

For example:

```
def function(x, i_add = False):
    if i_add == True:
        y = x+1

    return x, (Y)?
```

Given the example the results I'd like to have are:

```
function(3) -> 3
function(3, True) -> 3, 4
function(3, False) -> 3
```

I'm on python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return as many you need, If you return multiple values it will be `tuple` and if you return one value it will be just value

```
def function(x, i_add = False):
  if i_add == True:
     return x,x+1
  else:
     return x


re=function(10,True)  # or a,b=function(10,True)
print(type(re))    #tuple  (10,11)
r=function(10,False)
print(type(r))     # int      10
```

Comment: As above: exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 3):

With simple condition on `return` statement:

```
def function(x, i_add = False):
    return (x, x+1) if i_add else x
```

Comment: This is exaclty what I was searching for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Tuple:

```
def function(x,i_add = False):
    if i_add:
        y = x+1
        return x, y;
    else:
        return x

var1, var2 = function(3, True)

print(var1)
print(var2)
```

you can find more on geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-41-multiple-return-values-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

A DRY (Don’t repeat yourself) version using tuple concatenation

```py
def function(x, i_add=False):
    return (x,) + ((x+1,) if i_add else ())
```

Useful, if you have many default return arguments (e.g. `u,v,w,x,y,[z]`).
It always returns a tuple.